# Try to proof halting problem on a special TM

Tags: turing-machines

[image]

Hey guys,

Got a tricky question here.
I need to determine if this TM will ever halt on a empty word "".
Seems like it will halt but I can't proof it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Please update the question to show the source of the problem as well as why you think it is a tricky question. It will help others (me included) answer the question.

Comment: It is plausible that this Turing machine is one of the many Turing machines with 5 or 6 states that are not known to halt. It is pretty bad that the OP does not disclose/explain the source of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way how you would prove that a TM halts on a given input is to write out its computation (ie what is the relevant content of the tape, and what is the current state, for each time step) culminating in it halting. It is possible to design a TM that will halt, and where there is a short proof that it will halt, but the computation is so long that writing it out would be infeasible, but that is going to be a rare situation.

I've not actually worked it out carefully, but it seems that this particular TM will actually never halt. My impression is that the TM will generate an increasing area of $1$s around the initial position, cycling back and forth between growing left and growing right. The transition from $q_3$ to $q_5$ should never be taken (and neither should the transition from $q_1$ to $q_3$).

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to prove that a particular machine will never halt is to follow the first steps, long enough until you can find a pattern, and then prove by induction that the pattern will repeat. Maybe you can find something like "after 119 steps, and after 250 steps, the TM is in a state with a property X, and this seems to repeat, and I can prove that when the TM is in a state with property X then it will move to a state with property X again, without halting in between". Arno gave a suggestion what the property X would be for this particular TM.

There will be TMs behaving in a way that is "chaotic" enough so you cannot find such a pattern, or there might be a pattern that is too complicated for you to find.